# User folder missing after CLI user creation on Windows 7 with "net user"

Tags: windows-7

I've created a new user xxx by running `net user "xxx" /add`. The command completed successfully, but when I navigate to "`C:\Users`" folder there is no xxx user folder.

Comment: They may need to login first before the folder is created.

Comment: Just as a side note: Changing a user's name doesn't rename their profile folder either, so you can't assume they have the same name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

User profiles that are stored in C:\Users are created when someone logs in. Just creating a user using `net user "xxx" /add` will not be enough. It allows you to login with that user, but only after the first successful login will the user's profile folder be created.